# How to query balance and lock duration of staked tokens across multiple protocols

Tags: accounts, decentralized-exchange, staking

I would like to query the stake/LP balances across multiple defi protocols for a given account address. debank.com does something similar and can show the LP balance for a DEX, the stake balance and duration for Stargate, etc.  Is there a way to do this without querying each protocol's contract directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the stake/LP balances across multiple defi protocols for a given account address.

There is no standard for this. You need to

- Manually go through each protocol
- Study and understand their smart contract
- Create necessary deployment address lists and smart contract function calls to get the protocol-specific information

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that. I wonder how a website like debank does that in an efficient manner?  I guess that's a question for a later day.

Comment: They hire people to write the code.